# Entity framework error (a partial method may not have multiple defining declarations)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a project with entity framework and vs 2010 . This project was not until yesterday no problem but today when update model I encountered an error .

for example (170 error like this) :

```
error : A partial method may not have multiple defining declarations

error : The type 'taban.user' already contains a definition for 'QualityPart'
```

I've removed and re-built as a `model.edmx` but still encountered an error

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you only have one designer generated file for your context. Did you move the original?

When you updated the model a new one will have been generated (*if it couldn't find the original), and the result is it looks like you are defining the partial classes in two places with identical methods.
Do a search through your solution for files that define the context.

Comment: when remove model search in project files and delete model files then add new model